# PowerShell - Print Move-Item in Console

Tags: windows, powershell

I have the following code:

```
        $SchoolFolder = "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\School Folder\$StudentName\$Month. $MonthWrite\$Day. $DayWrite"
        $MP4Lenght = (Get-ChildItem -Path $RenderFolder).Length -ne "0"
        $MP4existsToCopy = Test-Path -Path "$RenderFolder\*.mp4"
        If (($MP4existsToCopy -eq $True) -and ($MP4Lenght -eq $True)) {
        Get-ChildItem $MyFolder | 
                Where-Object { $_.Length -gt 0KB} |
                Move-Item -Destination (new-item -type directory -force ($SchoolFolder + $newSub)) -force -ea 0
        Write-Host "Done!"
        }
```

I would like to know how do I make all correspondence in `$MP4Lenght` be printed in the console with the format `$MP4Lenght + "was moved"`, because that way I can know which files were moved.

Comment: Overall, you are not passing anything to allow you to do what you are asking. ```$MP4Lenght``` is a collection of file size, not name/not an individual file, and you are not iterating that collection anywhere in your loop.

Comment: ^^ plus [1] you're not showing where variables `$MyFolder`, `$Schoolfolder` or `$newSub` come from. [2] You're using Get-ChildItem **without** specifying a Filter or use switch `-File`. Do you want to move subdirectories as well with this? [3] using `$SchoolFolder + $newSub` is bad coding, use the [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) cmdlet to combine a path

Comment: Right, sorry for the confusion and messed up code. I added some information you requested and corrected the `$MyFolder` variable which was incorrect. I'm a beginner and I'm trying hard to learn as much as possible and optimize my codes, I'll follow your tips. As for listing the files, what would be the best way to get what I need? Basically I want everything moved from `$RenderFolder` to appear in the console as `File.mp4 has been moved`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "exist to copy" logic isn't really required, because if the file doesn't exist then get-childitem is not going to find it. Similarly with the check if MP4lenght is true.

The following will check if the file does not exist in the source and does exist in the destination and if that is true then write to the host that the file has moved:

```
$source = 'C:\Users\myuser\playground\powershell\Source\'
$destination = 'C:\Users\myuser\playground\powershell\Destination'
$files = Get-ChildItem $source -File | where-object {$_.Length -ne 0}

foreach ($file in $files) {

Move-Item $file.FullName -Destination .\Destination

if (-not(Test-Path $file.FullName) -and (test-path (Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $file.Name))) {
    Write-Host "$($file.name) has moved"
}
```

}

Comment: Excellent suggestion, I modified it a bit and it worked perfectly!

Sorry for the confusion in my first script, I'm a beginner so some things are still a bit confusing for me, so I occasionally write some redundant conditions.

The modified formula is in the comment below.

Thank you very much for your help and attention!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `-verbose`?

```
Move-Item -Destination (new-item -type directory -force ($SchoolFolder + $newSub)) -force -ea 0 -Verbose
```

***Update as per your comment.***

Try it this way...

```
$source      = 'C:\Users\myuser\playground\powershell\Source\'
$destination = 'C:\Users\myuser\playground\powershell\Destination'

Get-ChildItem $source -File | 
where-object {$PSItem.Length -ne 0} | 
ForEach-Object{
    Move-Item $PSItem.FullName -Destination '.\Destination'

    if (-not(Test-Path $PSItem.FullName) -and (test-path (Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $PSItem.Name))) {
        "$($PSItem.name) has moved"
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because `-Verbose` shows too much information, I would just like to see the name of the file that was moved, something like `File 01.mp4 was moved`. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Well, OK, but again, you are not passing a name in the loop to write out.

Answer (score 0):

Final script:

```
    $StudentName = Tyler
    $RenderFolder = "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Render"
    $MP4existsToCopy = Get-ChildItem $RenderFolder -File | where-object {$_.Length -ne 0}
    $SchoolFolder = "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\School Folder\$StudentName\$Month. $MonthWrite\$Day. $DayWrite"
    
    foreach ($file in $MP4existsToCopy) {
    
    Move-Item $file.FullName -Destination (new-item -type directory -force ($SchoolFolder)) # new-item - Serves to create the folder if it does not exist
    
    if (-not(Test-Path $file.FullName) -and (test-path (Join-Path -Path $SchoolFolder -ChildPath $file.Name))) {
        Write-Host "$($file.name) was moved!"
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).